# How to clear an item of every data type?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am making a trade system in my Minecraft map where I give players a diamond sword if they give me 2 golden swords.

For that I put 2 command blocks. On first one:

```
/give @p[hasitem={item=golden_sword, quantity=2.. }] diamond_sword
```

and on second one:

```
/clear @p[hasitem={item=golden_sword, quantity=2.. }] golden_sword 0 2
```

Here's the problem: the system will only clear the golden swords with data value 0, which means full health, but I want that the system clears the sword even if it is about to break. I can't skip data value as after data value I have to specify the amount that is 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix your problem by using more command blocks + a scoreboard. You can create 1 command block with the following command:

```
/clear @p golden_sword 0 1
```

then follow that command block up with a chain command block

```
/scoreboard players add @p swordCount 1
```

create another command block with the following command:

```
/clear @p golden_sword 1 1
```

then follow that command block up with a chain command block

```
/scoreboard players add @p swordCount 1
```

Repeat this process till you have 32 command blocks each trying to clear a golden sword of their respective data count.

Once the player has 2 points in the swordCount Scoreboard, any two golden swords would have been taken from them.

> You need to make sure that the command blocks turn off when the player gets two points, otherwise they will take ALL of their gold swords instead of two

> Reset their swordCount after/as the other command blocks turn off/get depowered/are no longer active

Answer (score 0):

Per [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/clear)

> If not specified, or if `-1`, all items that match `itemName: Item` are cleared, regardless of their data.

Hence, you should be able to use `-1` in place of the data value to clear all data values.